# react-router handle non matching path using plain javascript router config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How can I handle non matching path using plain javascript react router config?

```
const rootRoute = {
  component: 'div',
  childRoutes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: App,
      childRoutes: [
        require('./Page1'), // path = '/page1'
        require('./Page2')  // path = '/page2'
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If I navigate to '/random-undefined-page', how can I redirect it to '/'?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, you can try this:

```
path: '*'
component: App,
...
```

after all routes.

Comment: how can I redirect to '/' for path: '*' ?

Comment: for your answer, it is rendering component App, but the url is still  '/random-undefined-page'

Comment: @SooChengKoh, yeap, you right. May be source code fore react-router <Redirect /> helps you? (https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/a11a10bdd17a15ec7f0e7ab846d631677ac96baa/modules/Redirect.js )